# Field number validation

Tags: ajax, phtml, forms, validation, validate

I need to validate a field in a custom form. The field should be not required, and should validate if the content entered in it are numbers. I added the validation on the form which works. What does not work is the validation of this field.

`<input type="number" class="product-quantity" name="qty" data-validate="{ required: false, number: true }"/>`

I have tried using `number` and using `validate-number` but it does not help. After typing for example `abc` the validation passes.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to post the entire form code?

I suspect that you are missing the initialization of the mage/validation library.

Please see [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/validations/custom-form-validation.html)

In order for the validation rules to work. You must initialize the library within the scope of the form

Comment: Check comment below.

Answer (score 0):

@Ocastro I have something like that. As I said. The other rules work correctly. Only on this field neither `number` nor `validate-number` validation works for me.

```js
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#ask-container": {
                "VENDOR_MODULE/js/askAboutAvailability": {
                     "telephone": "<?= $block->getConfigData("telephone"); ?>",
                     "ajaxRequestUrl": "<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getPostUrl()) ?>"
            }
       }
  }
</script>
```